# Hydra is not going further after 5 passwords found, why?

Tags: hydra

I have a wordlist which has about 45 million lines. Hydra can find the data which I want. But the problem is that when hydra finds 5 passwords, it is not looking further and stopping working. I am not using -f parameter so that Hydra can find multiple password, but it is not going further after 5 passwords are found. What is the problem?

Note: I'm using the following syntax:

```
hydra -l test -P part1 -V domainName http-post-form "/somePath:parameters:denialMessage"
```

Comment: are you sure there are more passwords to be found?

Comment: Absolutely yes.